# Why devenv.exe doesn't start?

Tags: dual-boot, wine, playonlinux, vmware-player, dotnet

I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot installed on my PC. In the Windows 10 256GB partition I navigated with Wine Explorer to the Visual Studio folder and I saw the devenv.exe with the Visual Studio 22 icon, but when I start it shows:

[image: Captura de pantalla de 2023-10-01 20-27-31.png]

devenv in explorer:

[image: Captura de pantalla de 2023-10-01 20-29-42.png]

When I start devenv:

[image: Captura de pantalla de 2023-10-01 20-30-47.png]